# Structuremap recomposition some register parts in asp net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have a MVC project that i use structuremap for DI. I scan for a directory for all types of product and i register these in structuremap, so if some one adds some assembly in that directory i need that structuremap rescan that directory and add only the Products that are not register.

```
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(scan =>
                                                 {
                                                     scan.AssembliesFromPath(@"D:\Modules\");
                                                     scan.AssemblyContainingType(typeof (Product));
                                                     scan.AddAllTypesOf<Product>().NameBy(f=> f.Name);
                                                     scan.With(new ProductConvention());
                                                 }));
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }

    public class ProductConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.BaseType == null) return;

        if (type.BaseType.Equals(typeof(Product)))
        {
            registry.AddType(typeof (Product), type);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do that in structuremap THX.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to see when new files are added, then call

`ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan(...));`

Yes, you can use a FileSystemWatcher on a web server unless you are running in medium trust.  You need to know when files are added, otherwise you don't know when to tell StructureMap to scan for new types.

Comment: but i'm in web and i dont know if i can use FileSystemWatcher there and i nead only those that are not register in StructureMap